# Check if I am in range my wifi network

Tags: android

I was wondering if is any way to recognize which wifi is enabled in range of phone. I want to do application to run wifi scanner and if I am in range my wifi network I want to get toast. This is any nice tutorial  or examples how I can achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Androids [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) and getScanResults(), maybe do a scan before with startScan()